# Can not create database in rails using db:migrate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to make a very simple Rails program like this. At first, I made something in Rails by this command:

`rails generate scaffold Product \ title:string desciption:text image_url:string price:decimal`

I got no error, then I tried to made database by command `rails db:migrate` but I got this error

```
20191203044840 CreateProducts: migrating 
create_table(:products)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:`

undefined method string for :t:Symbol
C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/X/db/migrate/20191203044840_create_products.rb:4:in block in change
C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/X/db/migrate/20191203044840_create_products.rb:3:in change'
bin/rails:4:in require
bin/rails:4:in <main>

Caused by:
NoMethodError: undefined method string for :t:Symbol
C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/X/db/migrate/20191203044840_create_products.rb:4:in block in change
C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/X/db/migrate/20191203044840_create_products.rb:3:in change
bin/rails:4:in require
bin/rails:4:in <main>
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)`
```

I am very confuse because of this problem? I am a newbie and trying to make a simple program, so please help me, thank you very much.

Comment: please, paste the migration file

Comment: I am very sorry for my deficiency. Here is my `20191203044840_create_products` in `C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\X\db\migrate`

`class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :\
      t.string :title
      t.text :desciption
      t.string :image_url
      t.decimal :price, precision: 8, scale: 2

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end`

Answer (score 2):

Your migration file was incorrectly generated (probably because of `\` in the scaffold command). To fix it, remove `:\ t.string`:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change 
    create_table :products do |t| 
      t.string :title
      t.text :desciption
      t.string :image_url
      t.decimal :price, precision: 8, scale: 2
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I can solve my problem by your comment!

Comment: Good to know. If it helps, please consider upvoting&accepting.